Running Ollama on External GPU with Ori
I downloaded ollama and tried to run it on my MacBook Pro with a python script. It took awfully long to process (around 5 minutes) so I decided to use an external GPU. I since have a virtual machine through Ori, A100 80GB 4GiB VRAM 6 GiB Memory 70 GM NVMe.
I pip installed ollama and pulled llama 3 8gb version after connecting to the virtual machine using SSH.
When I run the script it still takes 5 minutes  to finish just like on my local computer, and when I check the GPU usage using pynvml it says 0%.
This GPU stuff is foreign to me, as I always relied on APIs, but I need to get away from token based pricing. Can somebody help describe how on earth I can get the script to run faster on the virtual machine? How can I make sure it’s using the GPUs that I rented?
I’m doing everything in Jupyter notebook

are you using any package like cudatoolkit to run the code specifically on GPU?

I installed cudatoolkit, but don’t know how to use it to get my ollama script to use the GPU
